# Promotion of illegal activity on social media platforms

Tags: social-media

Even though Tesla vehicles manufactured today have the internal hardware to be fully self-driving, they still need to undergo software upgrades before self-driving becomes fully functional. Furthermore, no state, as far as I know, allows autonomous vehicles to operate without a driver.

Nevertheless, videos are circulating on TikTok showing Tesla vehicles on the road with no driver and passengers in the back seat. Isn't TikTok legally required to remove these videos? I reported one and was notified that it didn't violate their community standards. I'm not trying to be a Karen, but I think they give people the wrong message and are dangerous.

Comment: I think it's police rather than TikTok who should be approaching those TikTok users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The First Amendment states

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or
> prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of
> speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to
> assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

It thus protects such videos. An analogous situation is that there is network news coverage of riots, bank robberies, terrorist attacks and assaults. Backpage was seized because it *facilitated* prostitution, not just reported or even encouraged it. That is basically where the line exists.

Comment: Then how can the FTC limit the f-word or sexually explicit material during primetime? Clearly, the government can intervene and limit speech in certain situations. Also, the news is a public service. TikTok is not covering these videos to educate the public. Their sole purpose is entertainment, which also encourages this kind of behavior.

Comment: I suggest searching First Amendment questions here: it is not an absolute freedom, e.g. there is no protection for fraud or death threats. Even *advocating* law-breaking is protected express, up to a point. The current standard is from  Brandenburg v. Ohio. Is it likely to produce imminent lawless action? No in the case of TikTok.

Comment: I'll look up that case, but are you saying the standard is that it must produce imminent lawless action? What about creating an age limit for certain content that doesn't produce imminent lawless action? Maybe TikTok can't remove the video, but law enforcement can definitely arrest the content creators. If I was a detective, I would do just that.

Comment: @user27343 The airwaves are considered a public good, and the courts have ruled that the government can prohibit their use without a license, and to make licenses contingent on following certain rules. You might want to do a web search or ask a separate question if you want more details. Note that these rules don't apply to cable or streaming services.

Comment: There is, however, a possible issue if TikTok is paying people for their content. Then it could be considered solicitation of a crime.

Comment: Even a video explaining how to set up a car for self-driving in violation of local law is likely protected by the First Amendment (see for example the FBI's analysis of The Anarchist Cookbook), although it could be used as evidence in prosecuting the crime itself.

Comment: @user27343: If you were a detective in the appropriate jurisdiction, *and* you were able to identify the perpetrator, *and* you thought you knew how to find them, *and* you didn't have any higher-priority cases such as violent crime, *and* you thought that the district attorney would likewise prioritize their resources toward prosecuting this case... do you start to see the problem?

Comment: I hear you. But when 500,000 eyeballs saw that stupid thing. I think it would be important enough to follow through. But that's just ME ...